# Angular make div wait for google chart to load

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to get a page with various google charts to load in e pretty way (i.e display loading icon until chart is ready). Now some of the charts have a corresponding div that includes some text /info relating to the chart.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="stat1 && stat2; else loading">
  <google-chart
                [title]="title"
                [type]="TYPE"
                [data]="data"
                [columns]="columnNames"
                [options]="options"
                [width]="width"
                [height]="height">
  </google-chart>

  <div class="myDiv" *ngIf="stat1 && stat3">
    my text
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>
  <div class="loading">
    my loading component
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

This works as far as displaying a loading icon until the chart is ready however the content of the div appears before the chart causing the loading to look messy.

Any help as to how I can make the div only display after the chart is loaded would be awesome, as I can't seem to find a working answer online or in documentation. (I'm likely not searching for the correct terminology)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you open [their documentation](https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts#ready) ?

> The ready event is emitted as soon as the chart got drawn and after every subsequent redraw.

```html
<google-chart (ready)="onReady($event)"></google-chart>
```

Maybe use that ?

Comment: I did, my belief was, that there would be a cleaner way to solve the issue using angular. If not 
I will use this approach, but i had hoped to learn an approach with angular that would also be applicable to future situations

Comment: @Samuel there is some insane and complicated ways of doing the same thing with angular only but I wouldn't recommend them